# jQuery TOOLS Tooltip trigger event

Tags: jquery

I, using Tooltip from [jQuery TOOLS](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html). I need to trigger tooltip from other a link, How can I do it? I have this:

```
<a href="#" id="open-tooltip1">1</a><a href="#" id="open-tooltip2">2</a>

<img id="san-paulo" title="San Paulo" class="point" src="img/siti_point.png" />
<img id="madrid" title="Madrid" class="point" src="img/siti_point.png" />

$("#map img[title]").tooltip();
```

Comment: If you want to insert code, select it and press the `{}` button on the toolbar or indent each line by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but maybe you just need to fire the mouseover event for the tooltipped element?

```
$("#someLink").click(function() {
    $("#tooltip").mouseover();
});
```

Comment: I have more than 1 tooltip: $("#map img[title]").tooltip();

Comment: Where are the links relative to the tooltips in your document? It would be helpful if you posted the relevant markup.